# Docker Compose down. Can I run a command before the actual stop?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gnu-screen

I have a setup with docker-compose which creates a [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) and runs a process in it.

That's because when I use the `docker-compose` with `-d` it will run the process in the background and attaching to the shell will actually give me a new shell.

What I need is the shell with the actual process...

So when I use my docker-compose script I use [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) to run the process in a screen instance.
When I open a shell I can connect to the shell of the running process using the `screen -r <screen_name>` command

But because it is running in a [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) the `docker-compose down` command won't actually stop properly and will stuck while trying to stop. Instead, I need to force the stop and this is not what I want because this is not the proper way of ending the process I have.

So I thought I need a way to define a stop command before the actual stopping happens.

Any tips are appreciated.

PS: Yes, it's Minecraft

EDIT 1: After the comment of Calum Halpin I don't need a screen anymore. So that I now only need a way to pipe something like "exit" to stdin.

EDIT 2: I guess I still need screen. When attaching to the shell I cant escape from there without killing the terminal session and therefore the process...

Comment: What command are you using to attach to the container? `docker attach` should attach you to the running process, not just start a new shell.

Comment: Oh, indeed `docker attach` works. In the VSCode Docker extension there is a context menu entry which is named "attach shell" (See https://i.imgur.com/mq3Dof4.png). I thought It does `attach` but what it really does is execute `docker exec` with `bash` - Confusion of da highest orda!

Comment: This also means I don't need a screen anymore - nice. So I just need a way to pipe something like "exit" to stdin now. Thanks @CalumHalpin